# Mysql if 0 display none whole TR

Tags: php, css, mysql

What I should do to add something like "dislpay: none;" to whole TR, if result from row credits is 0?
Should I use for this CSS, or mysql query?

```
<?php 
$username = "root"; 
$password = ""; 
$database = "aaa"; 
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", $username, $password, $database); 
$query = "SELECT * FROM table_name";




echo '<table border="0" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2"> 
      <tr> 
          <td> <div class="ddx">ID</div> </td> 
          <td> <div class="ddx">user ID</div> </td> 
          <td> <div class="ddx">name</div> </td> 
          <td> <div class="ddx">url</font> </div> 
          <td> <div class="ddx">credits</div> </td> 
      </tr>';

if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $field1name = $row["id"];
        $field2name = $row["usrid"];
        $field3name = $row["name"];
        $field4name = $row["url"];
        $field5name = $row["credits"]; 

        echo '<tr> 
                  <td>'.$field1name.'</td> 
                  <td>'.$field2name.'</td> 
                  <td>'.$field3name.'</td> 
                  <td>'.$field4name.'</td> 
                  <td><div class="ddxx">'.$field5name.'</div></td> 
              </tr>';
    }
    $result->free();
} 
?>
```

Screenshot from output: [image: https://i.ibb.co/yB9VGDT/Screenshot-1.png]

Comment: Limit these records in your sql query altogether, that is the preferred way.

Comment: I run query before `<table>` as well in case there are no results.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE credits <> 0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just take rows which value is not equal to `0`:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE CREDITS != 0
```

Answer (score 0):

inside `while` loop when you get the value of credits check if it equals to 0, if so go to next fetched line.

```php
if($field5name===0)
    continue;
```

*NOTE* The `continue` statement skips the current iteration of the loop and continues with the next iteration.